# Android Manifest mismatched tag

Tags: java, android, xml

I've been trying to open an existing Android project but I get an error on its Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.one.piano"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.evilduck.piano.PianoDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The error is:

> Error:(25, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [custom_view_keyboard-master] C:\Users\user\Desktop\oneapp.idea\AndroidManifest.xml:25: error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag

Which seems to be on the last "activity" on the previous line of the last.

edit:

values->string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Piano Showcase</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="remove">Remove</string>
<string name="scale">Scale</string>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove / from activity tag, and add / action tag
So it looks like:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.evilduck.piano.PianoDemoActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.one.piano"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.evilduck.piano.PianoDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: sorry about wrongly placed edits. I've been using Stack for a couple od days only.

Comment: i think your values folder have some problem